# How to Save image from UDPClient() bytearray in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, udp, video-streaming

I have a UDP server which receives data from my camera.
I'm facing to "Image data was invalid" error when I'm trying to display the bytearray as an image on my Adnroid/IOS device.

namespace SimpleContact.Dron
{

```
class Stream
{

    public async void test_stream()
    { 
        UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(11111);
        IPEndPoint hostEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.1"),0);
        receiver.Connect(hostEP);

        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 0);
        int i = 0;
        string fileName = "car_pic";


        while (true)
        {

            if (receiver.Available > 0)
            {

                 if( condition){

                   Debug.Write("Packet Received");
                   byte[] data = receiver.Receive(ref ep);

                   string picPath = Path.Combine(App.FolderPath, fileName + i.ToString() + ".jpg");

                    using (FileStream writer = File.Create(picPath))
                    {
                        writer.Write(data, 0 , data.Length);

                    }

                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);

                    DronController.displayImage.Source=        ImageSource.FromStream(()=>stream);
                   }


            }

    }
 }
```

}

Comment: You need to parse the inbound data to determine the start and end bytes of each image so the stream contains one complete image and then set the source from that stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot and this make sense. Can you pls explain with more details how to do it?(With some code examples if possible.)

Comment: This largely depends upon how you are sending those images from your server and the format of those images (i.e. png/jpeg/bmp/...).

Comment: I need to save the image on device disk(Adnroid/IOS) if the condition is true. I've updated the code and it's successfully saves the bytes on the file but it's invalid because the stream doesn't contain the full bytes for the complete image.

Comment: is it a webcam that is streaming a constant stream of frames?  or is it just sending one complete image at a time?  Are you sure it is using jpg/png as the image format?

Comment: It's sending video frames .. It's a Drone with video camera.  I need to retrieve the current frame and save as a jpeg image when clicking to the button. I've already did this with opencv/python.

Comment: @Arman,**retrieve the current frame and save as a jpeg image**,I guess that data [] does not appear to be a valid image format

Comment: yes you are right. and that's what I'd like to figure out. How to retrieve the correct data from video so I can save it as a jpeg image.